# Android Status Bar Notification is not updating when app is closed

Tags: java, android

I have an app which shows battery charge and temperature  in the status bar and notification bar. When the app is opened I can see the data updates in the status bar and notification. When I exit/close the app the status bar and notification is not updating its values. Why is the status bar and notification bar not updating when I close the app?

I use BroadcastReceiver to display the notification.

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    notificationMessage(context, intent);
}

private void notificationMessage(Context context, Intent intent){
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    int icon = R.drawable.battery_level_images;

    int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
    float cTemperature = (float) intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE, -1)/10;
    float fTemperature = celsiusToFahrenheit(cTemperature);
    float voltage = (float) intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_VOLTAGE, -1)/1000;
    int health = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_HEALTH, -1);
    String healthText = getHealthText(health);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
    .setContentTitle("" + level + "% | " + healthText)
    .setContentText(cTemperature + "\u2103 | " + fTemperature + "\u2109 | " + voltage + "V")
    .setSmallIcon(icon, level)
    .setWhen(0)
    .setProgress(100, level, false)
    .setOngoing(true)
    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
    .build();

    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
}
```

In my main activity class I turn on the notification with a checkbox.

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ............................

    myReceiver = new MyReceiver();

    ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
    batteryStatus = this.registerReceiver(mBatteryInfoReceiver, ifilter);

    ....................

 }

public void onToggleClicked(View view) {
    // Is the toggle on?
    boolean on = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

    if (on) {

        batteryStatus = this.registerReceiver(myReceiver, ifilter);
        SavingData.setNotificationState(true);

    } else {

        try{
            this.unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
        }catch (IllegalArgumentException  iae){
            iae.printStackTrace();  
        }

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.cancelAll();
        SavingData.setNotificationState(false);
    }
}
```

Here is my BroadcastReceiver in my AndroidManifest.

```
 <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register your `BroadcastReceiver` in your service and run it in your background. Running your service all the time might drain users battery. Beware :)

Comment: Thanks. What is a good way to run the service in the background and check the battery status without draining users battery. How does the android system do that when display battery percentage.

Comment: The android system sends a sticky broadcast whenever there is any change in battery leve. Kindly have a look at the documentaion for more details: http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html

Answer (score 0):

Once your activity is destroyed, your `BroadcastReceiver` registered via `registerReceiver()` will go away as well. You probably have a warning or error in LogCat pointing this out to you. Once your `BroadcastReceiver` is gone, you will stop updating the `Notification`.

Comment: What should I do so the BroadCastReceiver doesn't go away.

Comment: @EM2015 You need to register the broadcast reciever in a service, as pointed out by `Naresh R` .